# How to get udev?

Tags: rhel, yum, udev

I am using Redhat 8.4 distribution. How can I get udev on my system using yum? Which repository does contain udev?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDev, package `systemd-udev`, is in the `BaseOS` repository and should be already installed on your system -- it is part of the minimal installation.

Comment: apparently this is not the case for amazon linux (based on fedora)